# Htaccess - Check if file exists after url rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file, url-rewriting

I've created this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/account/(.*)$ accounts/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

to point an address like this: **example.com/john/account/img/1.jpg** to **example.com/accounts/john/img/1.jpg** and it works.

I know how to make a rule if a url to a phisical file not exists.

But now I want, after this rule, to set a folder for default images (or other file types). Referring to the example, I want to show image **example.com/default/img/1.jpg** (or directly **example.com/img/1.jpg**) if that image not exists in "john" folder (**example.com/accounts/john/img/1.jpg**).

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules:

```
# image doesn't exist in /accounts/john/<img>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/accounts/$1/$2 !-f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/account/(.+)$ default/$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/accounts/$1/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/account/(.+)$ accounts/$1/$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anubhava.

Meanwhile, I'm trying this code and seems to work.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/account/(.*)$ accounts/$1/$2 [NC,L]

# If file is not found into accounts folder (limited to "images")
# it is searched in root folder (/images)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^accounts/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/images/(.*)$ images/$2 [NC,L]
```